# How to remove the blank spaces in the title page?

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, titles

```
%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=3.2cm,rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 citecolor=blue,linkcolor=black}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\pagestyle{plain}
%字体设置
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
%\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={华文楷体 Bold}]{楷体} 
\setCJKmainfont[ ]{SimSun} 
\setCJKsansfont{微软雅黑}
\setCJKmonofont{华文楷体 Bold}  
%缩进与行距 
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.35}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %首行缩进
\usepackage{CJKnumb}    %中文数字
\usepackage[super,square,comma]{natbib}
%标题字体
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0, 0.439, 0.7529} %颜色设置
\usepackage{titlesec}


%文章所需要的包
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
 \usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{fontspec}




\setCJKfamilyfont{hei}{SimHei}                              %黑体  hei  
\newcommand{\hei}{\CJKfamily{hei}}   

\setCJKfamilyfont{akai}{Adobe Kaiti Std}                            %Adobe 楷体  akai  
\newcommand{\akai}{\CJKfamily{akai}}

\newcommand{\wuhao}{\fontsize{10.5pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont}



%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\hspace{2em}（\CJKnumber{\value{section}}）{\hspace{-.1em}}}    
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{ \hspace{2em}\arabic{subsection}. }
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14}\hei }
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14}\akai}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]%\sffamily
  {\ttfamily\color{black}}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 
%图表中文
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand\tablename{\hei 表}  
\renewcommand\figurename{\hei 图}  

 \captionsetup{ labelsep=period,  font=footnotesize, figurename=图,tablename=表}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\bfseries\color{black}{参考文献}}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}   
  \setlength{\bibsep}{1ex} 

  \makeatother

 \title{title } 

%\footnote{ }

 \author{{\Large {  author\makebox{$^{ 1}$},~~ author\makebox{$^{2 }$},~~author \makebox{$^{1,+}$}}}\\%四号，楷体
 \normalsize
   } 
  \date{}


 \wuhao
\begin{document}

 \maketitle



 \vskip.05in {\narrower  \noindent {\hei 摘要：}\ \
 凡事预则立，不预则废。实践证明，事发后的及时处置是社会治理的基本要求，在此基础上，提高预测预警预防各类风险能力，主动出击，杜微慎防，应该成为今后加强和创新社会治理、进一步提升群众安全感的重要任务。这就要求各地政法综治部门进一步增强工作主动性，既要审时度势，精准把握新形势下各种风险，又要改革创新，丰富完善风险防范、平安建设的体制机制。如今很多地方不断加大科技投入，“互联网+社会治理”渐成风气，下一步应该进一步加强智能开发、深度应用，拿出更多的科技“杀手锏”，使其对社会乱象的判断力、威慑力越来越强。凡事预则立，不预则废。实践证明，事发后的及时处置是社会治理的基本要求，在此基础上，提高预测预警预防各类风险能力，主动出击，杜微慎防，应该成为今后加强和创新社会治理、进一步提升群众安全感的重要任务。这就要求各地政法综治部门进一步增强工作主动性，既要审时度势，精准把握新形势下各种风险，又要改革创新，丰富完善风险防范、平安建设的体制机制。如今很多地方不断加大科技投入，“互联网+社会治理”渐成风气，下一步应该进一步加强智能开发、深度应用，拿出更多的科技“杀手锏”，使其对社会乱象的判断力、威慑力越来越强。
\vskip.05in \noindent {\hei 关键词：}\ \
 test



\begin{center}
\parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
{\centering \Large\textbf{title$^*$\\}} \vspace{3.2mm}%%四号，黑体
\begin{center}
{ author \makebox{$^{1}$},~~author\makebox{$^{2}$ },~~ author \makebox{$^{1,+}$}}\\[2pt]
\small{institutes}
\end{center}

\normalsize{\textbf{Abstract:}  

That is the theory put forth in "Amelia Earhart: The Lost Evidence," a two-hour documentary airing Sunday at 9 p.m. EDT on the History channel. It uncovers records, including this newly revealed photograph that shows what may be a healthy Earhart along with her navigator Fred Noonan, after they were last heard from.
The film also argues that after the pair crash-landed in the Japanese-held Marshall Islands, they were picked up by the Japanese military and that Earhart, perhaps presumed to be a U.S. spy, was held prisoner.That is the theory put forth in "Amelia Earhart: The Lost Evidence," a two-hour documentary airing Sunday at 9 p.m. EDT on the History channel. It uncovers records, including this newly revealed photograph that shows what may be a healthy Earhart along with her navigator Fred Noonan, after they were last heard from.
The film also argues that after the pair crash-landed in the Japanese-held Marshall Islands, they were picked up by the Japanese military and that Earhart, perhaps presumed to be a U.S. spy, was held prisoner.
 \vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Key words:}  test }}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

After compiling my files, the result is :

[image]

[image]

my expectation is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the second title/abstract is placed in a `\parbox`, and a `\parbox` cannot be broken across multiple pages. As a result, the entire second title/abstract is moved to the second page, because it can't fit on the first page. Hence, the solution is to not use a `\parbox`.

You can use `{\setlength\parindent{0pt} ... }` to locally set the `\parindent`, or add `\noindent` at the start of paragraphs to disable indentation. In LyX, you can alternatively right click in a paragraph and use the Paragraph settings.

In the code below I reduced the code to a minimum, which makes it easier to keep track of what happens.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=3.2cm,rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\newcommand{\hei}{}   

\title{title} 
\author{{\Large   author\makebox{$^{ 1}$},~~ author\makebox{$^{2 }$},~~author \makebox{$^{1,+}$}}\\%四号，楷体
 \normalsize
   } 
\date{}

\begin{document}

 \maketitle

 \vskip.05in {\narrower  \noindent {\hei 摘要：}\ \
 凡事预则立，不预则废。实践证明，事发后的及时处置是社会治理的基本要求，在此基础上，提高预测预警预防各类风险能力，主动出击，杜微慎防，应该成为今后加强和创新社会治理、进一步提升群众安全感的重要任务。这就要求各地政法综治部门进一步增强工作主动性，既要审时度势，精准把握新形势下各种风险，又要改革创新，丰富完善风险防范、平安建设的体制机制。如今很多地方不断加大科技投入，“互联网+社会治理”渐成风气，下一步应该进一步加强智能开发、深度应用，拿出更多的科技“杀手锏”，使其对社会乱象的判断力、威慑力越来越强。凡事预则立，不预则废。实践证明，事发后的及时处置是社会治理的基本要求，在此基础上，提高预测预警预防各类风险能力，主动出击，杜微慎防，应该成为今后加强和创新社会治理、进一步提升群众安全感的重要任务。这就要求各地政法综治部门进一步增强工作主动性，既要审时度势，精准把握新形势下各种风险，又要改革创新，丰富完善风险防范、平安建设的体制机制。如今很多地方不断加大科技投入，“互联网+社会治理”渐成风气，下一步应该进一步加强智能开发、深度应用，拿出更多的科技“杀手锏”，使其对社会乱象的判断力、威慑力越来越强。
\vskip.05in \noindent {\hei 关键词：}\ \
 test

\begin{center}
\centering \Large\textbf{title$^*$\\} \vspace{3.2mm}%%四号，黑体

{ author\makebox{$^{1}$},~~author\makebox{$^{2}$ },~~ author \makebox{$^{1,+}$}}\\[2pt]
\small{institutes}
\end{center}

{\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\textbf{Abstract:}  

That is the theory put forth in "Amelia Earhart: The Lost Evidence," a two-hour documentary airing Sunday at 9 p.m. EDT on the History channel. It uncovers records, including this newly revealed photograph that shows what may be a healthy Earhart along with her navigator Fred Noonan, after they were last heard from.
The film also argues that after the pair crash-landed in the Japanese-held Marshall Islands, they were picked up by the Japanese military and that Earhart, perhaps presumed to be a U.S. spy, was held prisoner.That is the theory put forth in "Amelia Earhart: The Lost Evidence," a two-hour documentary airing Sunday at 9 p.m. EDT on the History channel. It uncovers records, including this newly revealed photograph that shows what may be a healthy Earhart along with her navigator Fred Noonan, after they were last heard from.
The film also argues that after the pair crash-landed in the Japanese-held Marshall Islands, they were picked up by the Japanese military and that Earhart, perhaps presumed to be a U.S. spy, was held prisoner.
 \vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Key words:}  test }


\end{document}
```